Error in a table : "Missing number, treated as zero"
when I compile my table, I get the error "Missing number, treated as zero."
I looked, it tells me I added a zero but I can't find it in the table so I can't see what's wrong in my code.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\usepackage{textgreek}
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
            colspec={Q[c] Q[c] Q[c] Q[c] Q[c] Q[c] Q[c]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m]},
            cell{1}{1}={r}{c=2},
            colsep=5pt,
            row{1}={cmd=\textbf}}
            \toprule[blue]
         équation de la réaction : &  & \ch{C\sld} & + & \ch{1/2 O2\gas} & = &\ch{CO\gas}   \\
         \midrule[blue]
        état initial & $\chemxi=0$ & 3 & & 5 & & 0  \\
        état intermédiaire & $\chemxi$& $3-\chemxi$ & & $5-\frac{1}{2}\chemxi$ & & $0+\chemxi$ \\ 
        état final & $\chemxi_f$& $3-\chemxi_f$ & & $5-\frac{1}{2}\chemxi_f$ & & $\chemxi_f$ \\ 
        \bottomrule[blue]
    \end{tblr}
    %\caption{Valeurs numériques liées aux exemples}
    \label{tab:tableau_avancement}
\end{table}
 
\end{document}

Thanks

well the problem is cell{1}{1}={r}{c=2} , if you remove that or e.g. use cell{1}{1}={r} it compiles. But the key is somewhat underdocumented (and there is no index ...).

thanks for your response. what do you mean by " the key is somewhat underdocumented (and there is no index ...)." ?

Did you mean cell{1}{1} = {c=2}{r}? The span needs to come before the styles.

It meant that I tried to find a description about the arguments in the documentation and failed.
